# cytoscape js Hiding and restoring nodes with edges afterwards

Tags: cytoscape.js

There is a cool sample at [Hide nodes with animation](http://jsbin.com/gist/aedff159b0df05ccfaa5?js,output) by maxfranz.

I am having trouble reverting the state though.

Even if i keep the nodes + edges and then run restore on them. The nodes / edges do not reappear. Add doesnt work. Restore doesnt work. I must be missing something.

On clicking the node i hide (collapse) the linked nodes and I keep the removedElements in an array, and then store in a sratch with node specific namespace. When the node is clicked again, i want to restore (expand) the state on graph.

So i would expect something like this to work:

```
var tapped = e.cyTarget;
if (cy.scratch(tapped.id() + "_removed")) {
    var removedElements = cy.scratch(tapped.id() + "_removed");

    for (var i = removedElements.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        removedElements[i].restore();
    }
}
```

Note that the order of restoring the edges and nodes to be correct, first adding nodes then edges for them in the reverse order of removal.

Comment: This solution deletes a node and it's children (nodes plus edges), and can restore them: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30490567/collapsing-expanding-compound-node-in-cytoscape/67829648#67829648

Answer (score 0):

If you've restored hidden elements, they'll be hidden when you restore them.  Make sure their style is set appropriately.